# Having trouble creating a duplicate of a game object with input.getkeydown(KeyCode.Space) in C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

kinda new to coding so help would be appreciated. I'm trying to duplicate this GameObject "cube" in unity and I'm having trouble with it. what im trying to do is duplicate the cube and get it to stack on top of each other over and over.

I know if i got this to work it would duplicte it in the same postion so you would only see it duplicate in the higharchy.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube1;
    public void update()

    if(input.getKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    { 
         instantiate cube1; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you know the height of the cube, you are working with. In unity the default height is 1.0f(For the primitive cube).

Btw if your code is a pseudo code then its okey but if not, you need more training before writing such scripts, even tho this type of script is extremely easy to write.
(ps: i wrote this script in notepad++ hope it compiles :/)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// We start classes with capital letters in c# its a convention :)
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Same applies to public class fields & Properties
    // Marking a MonoBehaviour field as public will allow you to directly assign values to it
    // inside the editor
    public GameObject OriginalCube;

    // Same can be achieved with private fields using the serializefield attribute
    [SerializeField]
    private float cubeHeight = 1.0f;

    // In case you would like to store the duplicated cubes
    public List<GameObject> Cubes = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Adding the first cube to the list, i assume your cube is already in the scene
        Cubes.Add(OriginalCube);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        { 
            // We instantiate a new cube and add it to the list
            Cubes.Add(Instantiate(Cubes[Cubes.Count - 1]);
            // We ask the previous cube position (the one we copied)
            Vector3 previousCubePosition = Cubes[Cubes.Count - 2].transform.position;
            // then we assign a new position to our cube raised by "1 unit" on the y axis which is the up axis in unity
            Cubes[Cubes.Count - 1].transform.position = 
                new Vector3(previousCubePosition.x, previousCubePosition.y + cubeHeight, previousCubePosition.z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ight guys will test this out, just a quick question where is it that you guys learned to code so well? I've been coding for 6 months now and I still haven't truly gotten the hang of it?

Comment: Me university, but i can recommend pluralsight https://www.pluralsight.com/browse/software-development/c-sharp, and the new Unity Learn https://learn.unity.com/?_ga=2.249070031.97663470.1567690406-709504176.1553518537site,  :)

Comment: error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add this namespace `System.Collections.Generic;`, code updated

Comment: btw if you are using visual studio, pressing "ctrl + ." will give you suggestion about how to fix the issue, when your cursors is on the red line

Comment: Now im getting error message Assets/Scripts/Cube.cs(33,44): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Comment: I updated it but i hardly recommend to try to solve this problem alone!, this would help you learn

Comment: @GodBleach When the compiler says cannot convert x to y, it means that the programmer made some mistake and tried to convert a Banana to an apple, which is not really possible, for example `int 5 = "Five";` will say Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Int32t' to 'System.String' which is true cos you are trying to assign a "text" to a "number" field

Comment: @GodBleach Some days ago i read about this, and it seemed very promising i hardly recommend this tutorial to you: https://learn.unity.com/project/creator-kit-beginner-code , the tutorial introduces c# to you by making an Adventure RPG :)

Comment: ok thanks, I will check it out I'm currently taking the course on udemy.com about 2d unity programing. I've learned quite a bit but want to learn more. I try to code once a day from like 1-8 hours long depending on how I feel. It's a lot to absorb, sometimes I forget things like capitalizing variable names.

Comment: @GodBleach Good luck on your journey :)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can have your goal achieved, is to add to your newly instantiated object's y position a constant amount. This constant amount will be increased each time you create a new duplicate of your object.

```
public GameObject cube1;

private int instantiateCounter = 0;

public float PULL_UP_AMOUNT = 30f;

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        instantiateCounter++;
        GameObject newCube = Instantiate(cube1);
        newCube.transform.position = new Vector3(cube1.transform.position.x, cube1.transform.position.y + instantiateCounter * PULL_UP_AMOUNT, cube1.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

The constant amount we're talking about is `PULL_UP_AMOUNT`.

Keep in mind, you can access your new duplicate's properties by saving the result of `Instantiate` method inside a new `GameObject`, just like I did.

Comment: I would avoid calling PULL_UP_AMOUNT a constant, i would rather call it by a fix value